# Objective C: How to make UIScrollView end before hidden UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I will like to be able to make the UIScrollView end before a hidden element(UIView). I am unable to remove modeView from the scene as the functionality is currently disabled, but may be enabled in the future and once the functionality has to be enabled, the UIView (modeView) has to be shown.

[image]

I have tried the following to reduce the height when UIVIew *modeView is hidden, however the UIScrollView still did not end at the correct position.

[image]

The following is the code:

```
modeView.hidden = YES;
    
int contentViewHeight = 1000;
    
NSLog(@"modeView Height: %f", modeView.frame.size.height);
    
if(modeView.hidden == YES) {
   contentViewHeight = contentViewHeight - modeView.frame.size.height;
}
else {
   contentViewHeight = 1000;
}

contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [Helper getScreenWidth], contentViewHeight);
[scrollView addSubview:contentView];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake([Helper getScreenWidth], contentViewHeight);
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are not changing scrollView height based on condition. It needs to be updated.

Add this line as well:

scrollView.frame = CGRectMake([Helper getScreenWidth], contentViewHeight);

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust scroll view `frame` to wherever you want to show it. And you need to adjust `contentSize` to whatever you want to show within the scroll view.

So usually the `contentSize` is larger than `frame`. When it isn't, there is nothing to scroll as user sees all the content already. In your case both of them seem to have height of `contentViewHeight` which means there will be nothing to scroll.

So in your case you should always have a fixed `contentSize` such as `CGSizeMake([Helper getScreenWidth], contentViewHeight)`. But the scroll view frame needs to be computed taking into consideration both parent view and `modeView`.

I am not completely sure where this code is and what is `self`. But assuming that `self` is a subclass of `UIViewController` then it has a property `view` which is used to display all of your content. Then try something like this:

```
CGSize viewSize = self.view.frame.size; // A Size of my "screen"
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(viewSize.width, 1000.0);
scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, viewSize.width, viewSize.height - modeView.frame.size.height);
```

This is assuming a lot of things from your layout though. I would in your place consider that you use constraints to define all of your layout. But that is another topic.